# Rspec + integration testing + activemodel = confused :)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have following problem, which I don't understand:
I have an User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  private
    def generate_token(column)
      begin
        self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
      end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
    end
end
```

and an integration test:

```
it "should sign an user in" do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  visit root_path
  click_link "Sign in"
  fill_in :email, with: user.email
  fill_in :password, with: user.password
  click_button
  controller.should be_signed_in
  click_link "Sign out"
  controller.should_not be_signed_in
end
```

which fails on

```
User.exists?
```

with

```
NameError uninitialized constant User::User
```

replacing mentioned row with

```
self.class.exists?
```

fixes it..
Can someone please lead me out of confusion? :)
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that method is running inside a scope namespaced with User, maybe you are defining it through a module (just guessing). By the way, you can write as following:

```
::User.exists?
```

And it should start the "namespace resolving" from root.

Comment: It is really strange, I found out that I had a typo in spec_helper.rb, so I was not running specs in test environment.. Running them in test seems to fix it.. And another interesting thing was, that spec passed with rspec command, but not via autotest.. I will write more after I'll dig deeper. Thanks for the :: thing, I didn't know that :)